# Can I enable the "Function doesn't return a value on all code paths" warning for "Value Type" functions?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, return-type

I noticed some of my functions aren't throwing the `"Function doesn't return a value on all code paths"` warning, even though not all of their paths return a value. After some experimenting and research, it looks like functions that return a "Value Type" data type (as defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types)) do not throw the warning, while functions that return a "Reference Type" data type will throw the warning. I would assume this is because Value Types have a default value (generally `0`), while the default value for Reference types is `Nothing`.

So I can understand why the warning wouldn't generally be thrown for Value Type functions. However, sometimes it's important to make sure the function explicitly returns a value on all paths, even if that function returns a Value Type. Is it possible to enable this warning for functions that return a Value Type, like Boolean, double, or an enumerator functions?

---

EDIT: By request, here's an example of a function that does NOT throw the warning:

```
Function TestFunction() As Double
    If Now.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
        Return 10
    End If
End Function
```

(if I change the return type to String, I DO get the warning)

Comment: Do you have an example? I get the message even for value type.

Comment: I get the message as well for value types, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: I edited and added an example of a function that doesn't throw the warning. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional, Version 15.9.11.

Comment: Do you have this somewhere?  #Disable Warning BC42353  or maybe a <NoWarn> in the vbproj  or under the Compile section "Warning configuration" of your project property.

Comment: @the_lotus found it! You led me right to it. The template I used to create my project had the `Function returning intrinsic value type without return value` notification set to `None` under Project Settings --> Compile --> Warning Configurations. If you'll post as an answer I'll mark as solution. Thanks!

Comment: @the_lotus - make your comment a Answer so the OP can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the **Project Properties > Compile**, there's a section called "**Warning configurations**". In there, you can set if you want these type of condition as warning, error or none.

In this case, the condition **"Function returning intrinsic value type without return value"** may be set to "None". It would also be possible to disable it with `#Disable Warning BC42353`